# SoapUI request payload missing from Jenkins logs

Tags: rest, logging, soapui

got a very weird and frustrating situation.

I'm currently testing REST services using SoapUI, in Ubuntu. In the soapui.log, but also in the text files generated for each request, i can see the entire information about each request (request headers, url and payload, as well as response headers, and message. This works both when calling the testrunner from the UI, as well as from the CLI.

However, JUST the request payload (JSON) is missing when i run the tests via Jenkins and check the logs. This is the first information the developers need to know, when investigating an issue.

I have little control and visibility over exactly what Jenkins does. I do know that it is using the Jenkins user to run the testrunner via CLI.

Can anyone think of any setting or configuration that might cause the request payload not being logged? I assume Jenkins is doing/configuring something different, but i can't tell what.

Comment: What command do you use in Jenkins to execute the test? Is it same as the one that you use thru CLI?

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same, except for some file paths:
/opt/SoapUI-5.3.0/bin/testrunner.sh -r -j -f target/test-reports API-Tests.xml

Comment: Is there any soapui-settings.xml different for your machine? Have you tried absolute path of the project?

Comment: Issue still reproduces with absolute path.

The soapui-settings file differ a lot,m since my local file contains a lot of settings i did in the user interface. But i see no parameter in that file, that could make a difference.

Please note that the request payload is the only thing missing from the logs. The rest of the information is there.

Comment: You can copy setting file from your machine to jenkins machine where it is referring to (path); replace if there are any local paths. Is it happening for a specific test step or for test steps?

Comment: Will try to replace the properties file. it is happening for all requests, not any specific test step.

Answer (score -1):

Another option may be to run your testcases using SoapUI maven plugin on jenkins

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>nz.geek.karit.app</groupId>
   <artifactId>app</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>app</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <!--Add the repository for where Maven can find the soapUI Plugin-->
   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
         <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--This is the version of soapUI to grab from plugin repo-->
            <!--At the time of writing the 3.0.1 plugin had not been created-->
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <!--The location of your soapUI setting file-->
               <projectFile>/home/test/test.xml</projectFile>
               <!--Where to place the output of the run-->
               <outputFolder>/home/test/output/</outputFolder>
               <!--Make the jUnit results file-->
               <junitReport>true</junitReport>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>soapUI</id>
                  <!--Run as part of the test phase in the Maven lifecycle-->
                  <phase>test</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <!--Run the test phase of eviware:maven-soapui-plugin-->
                     <goal>test</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

The output folder should contain the detail logs.

For more info refer :
http://blog.karit.geek.nz/2009/08/using-soapui-to-do-testing-as-part-of.html

Comment: This Maven configuration is seriously outdated, and your answer contains a lot of irrelevant information (such as dependency on JUnit).

Comment: Thanks @SiKing for your comments , I have updated the pom